# How to write better functions for assigning state variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues writing more reusable, maintainable code for a project I'm working on. I'm using useState to take data from an object variable and storing it. There's two buttons that are used to go to the next object.

The first card initially shows the 1st blog post and the second should always show the next blog post. There should always be a loop so that posts can be 'scrolled' indefinitely.

Here is a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-meadow-12cdup?file=/src/App.js) of what I currently have. What would be a better way to write this so that it's scaleable and not error prone?

```
// total posts
  let numPosts = posts.length - 1;

  // get first blog post
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(posts[0].title);
    setText(posts[0].text);
    setTime(posts[0].time);
    setDay(posts[0].day);
    setDate(posts[0].date);
  }, []);

  // get second blog post
  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle2(posts[1].title);
    setText2(posts[1].text);
    setTime2(posts[1].time);
    setDay2(posts[1].day);
    setDate2(posts[1].date);
  }, []);

  // next blog post
  const increase = async () => {
    if (counter < numPosts) {
      setCounter((counter) => counter + 1);

      setTitle(posts[counter + 1].title);
      setText(posts[counter + 1].text);
      setTime(posts[counter + 1].time);
      setDay(posts[counter + 1].day);
      setDate(posts[counter + 1].date);
      // get next post title
      setTitle2(posts[counter + 2].title);
      setText2(posts[counter + 2].text);
      setTime2(posts[counter + 2].time);
      setDay2(posts[counter + 2].day);
      setDate2(posts[counter + 2].date);
    } else if (counter === numPosts) {
      setCounter((counter) => (counter = 0));

      setTitle(posts[0].title);
      setText(posts[0].text);
      setTime(posts[0].time);
      setDay(posts[0].day);
      setDate(posts[0].date);
      // get next post title
      setTitle2(posts[1].title);
      setText2(posts[1].text);
      setTime2(posts[1].time);
      setDay2(posts[1].day);
      setDate2(posts[1].date);
    }
  };

  // previous blog post
  const decrease = async () => {
    if (counter === 0) {
      setCounter((counter) => (counter = numPosts));

      setTitle(posts[counter + numPosts].title);
      setText(posts[counter + numPosts].text);
      setTime(posts[counter + numPosts].time);
      setDay(posts[counter + numPosts].day);
      setDate(posts[counter + numPosts].date);
      // get next post title
      setTitle2(posts[counter + numPosts + 1].title);
      setText2(posts[counter + numPosts + 1].text);
      setTime2(posts[counter + numPosts + 1].time);
      setDay2(posts[counter + numPosts + 1].day);
      setDate2(posts[counter + numPosts + 1].date);
    } else if (counter > 0) {
      setCounter((counter) => counter - 1);

      setTitle(posts[counter - 1].title);
      setText(posts[counter - 1].text);
      setTime(posts[counter - 1].time);
      setDay(posts[counter - 1].day);
      setDate(posts[counter - 1].date);

      // get next post title
      setTitle2(posts[counter].title);
      setText2(posts[counter].text);
      setTime2(posts[counter].time);
      setDay2(posts[counter].day);
      setDate2(posts[counter].date);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `useReducer` hook for more concrete state management.

Refer: [useReducer Hook Reference](https://www.react.express/hooks/usereducer)

Comment: Would I replace the current setState functions inside my increase() and decrease() functions to a dispatch? Could I have two reducers, one for increase() and one for decrease() ?

I understand what my initial state would be for each case but I don't know how I would reference the counter from within the useReducer hook so that there is a loop like in my example.

Comment: Yes you should create 1 reducer and replace increase and decrease with dispatch. If that doesn't give you much flexibility, you can use 2 different reduces for both the posts. Refer this tutorial for understanding `useReducer`: https://youtu.be/kK_Wqx3RnHk